# Link to mu4e e-mails in MacOS

Tags: mu4e

My e-mail client is mu4e. I can easily create links to org-mode files via `org-mu4e-store-and-capture`, as described here https://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e/Org_002dmode-links.html, for instance.

Now I would like to additionally link from some non-emacs MacOS app, such as the calendar, to e-mails in mu4e. I have to solve two problems for this:

(1) When I have already a link to an e-mail message of the form `mu4e:msgid:....@....com` (like the links stored in org mode). How can I open such a link via emacsclient?

I would like to run the command

```
/usr/local/bin/emacsclient --eval 'SOMEFUNCTION "mu4e:msgid:....@....com"'
```

in a shell, where `SOMEFUNCTION` is the function that org-mode calls when a link of the form `mu4e:msgid:....@....com` is clicked. How can I determine the name of this function, in order to use it in the above shell command?

(2) When I am viewing an e-mail in mu4e, I would like to call a function that provides me with the `mu4e:msgid:....@....com` link to this e-mail. This happens (among other things) in `org-mu4e-store-and-capture`, how can I use this to copy a link to the clipboard in order to paste it to another MacOS application?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

1. To open a link from a string:

```
(org-link-open-from-string "mu4e:msgid:....@....com")
```

2. To make the stored link the latest kill in the kill ring:

```
(advice-add 'org-store-link :after
        (lambda (arg &optional interactive?)
          (when (or (eq major-mode 'mu4e-headers-mode)
                    (eq major-mode 'mu4e-view-mode))
            (kill-new (caar org-stored-links)))))
```